# vba sql query whit data type double

Tags: sql, types, double, where-clause

i want to make a sql query in access where condition whith double type but allways data type error.

sql = "SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 = 1,2"
or 
sql = "SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 = '1,2'"

help me please

thanks

Comment: What is 113? A table Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 IN (1.2)"
```

Comment: thanks, y try but returns me less records, y try 1.2 and works fine. sql = "SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 IN (1.2)"

Comment: it is comma or double? double means u can add more values using comma and u can check...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `DOT` instead a `KOMMA` as decimal seperator.

```
SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 = 1.2 or sql = "SELECT * FROM 113 WHERE Esp1 = 1.2
```